# Is it possible to access a substring of a Java String without creating a new String object?

Tags: java, string

I just want to read it as its own "String" but a view is fine -- I don't need it to be materialized as a separate object. I'd prefer to not incur the overhead of creating a new object.

Comment: What overhead?  Don't assume there is one until you see evidence for it.

Comment: Don't micro optimise unless you have solid stats that tell you that it is an overhead that you cannot accept.

Comment: In addition, aren't the results of `substring` (and most/all of the other string operations) backed by the same `char` array?

Comment: Yes, they are. The new String object has it's own values for ``offset`` and ``length`` but uses the same ``char[]``.

Comment: That was true at the time of writing, but for anyone reading this now, note that as of Java 7, `substring` returns a new `String` object with a copy of the underlying `char[]`.

Answer (score 6):

You can access the characters one by one with the `charAt()` method. If you already have a character array allocated, you could copy the characters into it, and use that. Neither of these would involve creating any more objects. But that's about it.

Note that if you call `substring()`, the `String` class doesn't copy the underlying `char[]` -- it only creates the new `String` object itself, and they share the `char[]`.

Comment: Using the char[] would be the answer if a String object is not required for whatever he is doing.

Comment: The part about `substring` is no longer true as of Java 7 (see [blog post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/changes-stringsubstring-java-7)).

Answer (score -5):

No, the String object is immutable.

Answer (score -5):

The only thing I could think of is setting it to the same variable that it originally was.

Ex:

```
var aString = "test";
aString = aString.substring(2);
```

Comment: I guess the question is about java not javascript/ecmascript